# "Bagagem" e "bagagens" podem ser intercambiáveis? Contáveis e incontáveis?

Tags: número-gramatical

Tenho lido, e ouvido, frases semelhantes às abaixo:

- Eu trouxe minha bagagem ontem. Maria trouxe a sua hoje. Nossa bagagem já está no carro.
- Eu trouxe .... Maria trouxe...  Nossas bagagens já estão no carro.
- Eu estou levando três malas grandes.  É a minha bagagem.
- As minhas bagagens estão naquele canto. São três malas grandes.

Afinal, **bagagem** pode ser contável e incontável em situações idênticas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Bagagem" é um "conjunto" de objetos: ou seja, é contável mas pode ser usado no singular para se referir a um número de objetos.

Portanto o terceiro exemplo ("bagagem" = 3 malas) é trivialmente correto.

O primeiro exemplo ("Nossa bagagem já está no carro.") também está correto, com o detalhe de que aqui a bagagem é conjunta (minha e da Maria).

O segundo exemplo ("Nossas bagagens já estão no carro.") mais uma vez está correto, só que aqui a identidade dos dois conjuntos é mantida, ou seja, há a minha bagagem e a bagagem de Maria.

Quanto ao quarto exemplo ("As minhas bagagens estão naquele canto"), eu diria que é preferível evitar o plural, a menos que se pretenda separar a bagagem em subconjuntos (por exemplo, "minhas bagagens" = bagagem de mão + bagagem despachada).

Answer (score 1):

No dia-a-dia, é muito comum, nós brasileiros, usar palavras no singular (bagagem) e no plural (bagagens) para as mesmas situações.

Nesse contexto, se referindo as suas malas, tanto faz você dizer:
"Nossa bagagem" ou "Nossas bagagens", "As minhas bagagens" ou "A minha bagagem".

A tendência é usar palavras no singular: "Nossa bagagem", "A minha bagagem".

Fique tranquilo, que a mensagem (a sua bagagem ou malas) será transmitida para quem quer que seja.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que há uma súbtil diferença de semântica.

Por exemplo: dizer *bagagem* no singular se levarmos só uma mala refere-se à mala ou aos conteúdos da mala. Mas se dissermos no plural referir-se-ia necessariamente ao contéudo da mala e não à mala em si que é singular.

> Estou a levar uma mala, são as minhas bagagens.

Neste exemplo bagagens não se podia referir à mala (contentor) por não concordar em número. O que a gramática chama a esta propriedade não sei precisar.